# Close Google Chrome tab (command + w) closes window

Tags: google-chrome

I upgraded to Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 and Command + w is now closing the active window instead of closing the active tab only. Is there a "hidden" shortcut for closing the active tab only?

Comment: Interesting. Command + W closes the active tab for me. Note that **Shift** + Command + W closes the active window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I just needed to restart the computer. The keyboard mappings are now working as expected.

Comment: Really strange. I faced this issue and just did what you said. Works good again.

Comment: Same issue here, same fix (OSX Yosemite, Chrome 38.0.2125.111).

Comment: ^ Same issue here with Chrome 38 on Yosemite. Weird.

Comment: Same issue here with Chrome 38 on Yosemite too. And same fix... Really weird.

Comment: i have also seen this issue on both mavericks and yosemite. not consistently though, just every once in awhile it acts as though i hit cmd+shift+w instead of cmd+w, (i am certain i didn't, at least not all the times it has happened).

Answer (score 2):

I also see this occasionally. It seems more like a focus bug, though. It only happens after I've been tabbing between applications and I tab back to Chrome. For some reason, in these cases, Chrome hasn't given the active window focus and cmd+w closes the window instead of the tab.

Comment: I'm seeing this in Chrome 44; happens, only sometimes, when tabbing between full-screen apps on OS X. Definitely seems like a focus thing.

Comment: Adding to this: when my window looses focus after tabbing back, I can scroll and keyboard events are sent to the window (but behave oddly), i.e., I hit the spacebar to scroll down on a page and it scrolls as far down as it can, like the keypress event is getting continually triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with the same version and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes just the active tab. Maybe you installed something the re-mapped the keyboard shortcuts (such as an extension)?

Comment: -1: just speculation; doesn't attempt to answer the question

Comment: Cant understand the down vote, how do you answser this in another way?

Comment: This…isn't really an answer. Things like these should (as far as I'm concerned) usually be posted as comments ([like this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72284/close-google-chrome-tab-command-w-closes-window/72288#comment83964_72284)). The question itself _is_ rather hard to answer; though if you _knew_ of “a "hidden" shortcut for closing the active tab only”, you could post that as an answer.